# cleft sentences with base form of the verb and infinitives

Tags: grammar, verbs, clefts

Are we supposed to use the base form of the verb in a cleft sentence or an infinitive? or a gerund? or maybe it's a matter of personal choice?

"What I really hate is _____ out."
a. go     b.    to go     c. going

"All you need to do is trust me." is obviously the correct form. But is it because of "all" that we use the base form "trust"? What about cleft sentences with "what"?

"what you need right now is ___________."?
a. to calm down        b. calm down         c. calming down

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a matter of (1) what the predicate is (with _hate_, either (a) or (b) is possible), and (2) what you mean (with _need_ in a wh-cleft, (b) is ungrammatical -- _need_ requires a _to_ infinitive -- while (a) and (c) are correct, but they don't mean the same thing -- in (c), somebody is calming you down, but in (a) you calm down by yourself).

Comment: I think JL means that  either b. or c. is possible with "hate".